# Updating Laravel application from git on multiple servers

Tags: php, git, laravel

I am working on development of a web app (for learning) in Laravel and I`m using Bitbucket for source control. It will be deployed on couple servers (20 or so, perhaps more over time), and I would like to be able to update all of them as the app changes over time. 
The problem is that I will not have SSH access to most of those servers so I wont be able to use a simple "git pull" (a server we test on does not even have git installed so shell_exec is not an option also).

My plan was to make a script that will download latest zip from Bitbucket server, unpack it overwriting the old code, and then running a Laravel script to run migrate (for eventual database changes).

Is there maybe a more sensible way of doing this?

Comment: This might not be the best place to ask a question like this. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is CI/CD, i.e. Continues Integration/ Continues Delivery. There are so many ways to automatically deploy or pull a code over server. You can use following methods

> [Automating Deployment to EC2 Instance With Git](http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2015/03/28/automating-deployment-with-git/)
>
> [Using Bitbucket for Automated Deployments](http://brandonsummers.name/blog/2012/02/10/using-bitbucket-for-automated-deployments/)
>
> [CI\CD workflow with BitBucket Cloud, Bamboo, AWS CodeDeploy](https://medium.com/devoops-and-universe/ci-cd-workflow-with-bitbucket-cloud-bamboo-aws-codedeploy-2228f9e8d3d3)
>
> [Bitbucket - Manage Web Hooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html)

Apart from this you can find so many articles on this, but if you wants to automate the process at laravel level then use [Laravel Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/envoy)

Comment: He doesn't have access to the server

Comment: But he has FTP access, he can apply any one method which is feasible.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: First, thanks for the answers. I will have FTP access, but I`m not sure about having Git installed on the servers... maybe it will be easiest for me to have git in the requirements for server admins and use one of these methods.